# Gitlab pipeline has no deployed releases

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm running a deployment using Gitlab CI

I keep getting this error.

```
secret/review-swagger-rn2vs9-secret replaced
No helm values file found at '.gitlab/auto-deploy-values.yaml'
Deploying new stable release...
UPGRADE FAILED
Error: "review-swagger-rn2vs9" has no deployed releases
ROLLING BACKError: timed out waiting for the condition
Uploading artifacts...
00:01
WARNING: environment_url.txt: no matching files    
WARNING: tiller.log: no matching files             
ERROR: No files to upload                          
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

- Review your Cluster credentials.

  - delete the token
  - recreate a token or more likly try to use the "default" token.
- recreate the whole Gitlab <-> Kubernetes connection
- try the connection not at project level, try it on group or root level (this was my issue) on Gitlab